# Jquery zoom in and zoom out works with jerks instead of smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a canvas. I have to zoom it until zoom in button is pressed and zoom out it until zoom out button is pressed. I have managed to get it to work but it works with delays. and it keeps zooming in or out even when I have released the button. This is what I have tried so far. Please help me. You can check it at the live site over [Here](http://colorpeutic.com/product.php?id=16).

```
<script language="javascript">
    var timeout, clicker = $('#zoomin'),
        clicker2 = $('#zoomout');

    clicker.mousedown(function() {
        timeout = setInterval(function() {
            var wd = $("#canvas").width();
            var ht = $("#canvas").height();
            wd = parseInt(wd) + 250;
            ht = parseInt(ht) + 250;
            $("#canvas").animate({
                width: wd,
                height: ht
            });
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
            ctx.drawImage(outlineImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
            redraw();
        }, 500);

        return false;
    });

    clicker2.mousedown(function() {
        timeout = setInterval(function() {
            var wd = $("#canvas").width();
            var ht = $("#canvas").height();
            wd = parseInt(wd) - 250;
            ht = parseInt(ht) - 250;
            if (wd < 500) {
                return false;
            }
            $("#canvas").animate({
                width: wd,
                height: ht
            });
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
            ctx.drawImage(outlineImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
            redraw();
        }, 500);

        return false;
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        clearInterval(timeout);
        return false;
    });

    $("#zoomout").mousedown(function() {
        var wd = $("#canvas").width();
        var ht = $("#canvas").height();
        wd = parseInt(wd) - 250;
        ht = parseInt(ht) - 250;
        if (wd < 500) {
            return false;
        }
        $("#canvas").animate({
            width: wd,
            height: ht
        });
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
        ctx.drawImage(outlineImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
        redraw();
        console.log(wd + ":" + ht);
    });

    $("#zoomin").click(function() {
        var wd = $("#canvas").width();
        var ht = $("#canvas").height();
        wd = parseInt(wd) + 250;
        ht = parseInt(ht) + 250;
        $("#canvas").animate({
            width: wd,
            height: ht
        });
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
        ctx.drawImage(outlineImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
        redraw();
        console.log(wd + ":" + ht);
    });
    $("#zoomout").click(function() {
        var wd = $("#canvas").width();
        var ht = $("#canvas").height();
        wd = parseInt(wd) - 250;
        ht = parseInt(ht) - 250;
        if (wd < 500) {
            return false;
        }
        $("#canvas").animate({
            width: wd,
            height: ht
        });
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
        ctx.drawImage(outlineImage, 0, 0, wd - 1, ht - 1);
        redraw();
        console.log(wd + ":" + ht);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it works fine for me on chrome! what's your browser?

Comment: You have cleartimeout at wrong place.

Comment: The zoom should continue to happen until the button is pressed. Not gradually zoom in steps of 250px..

Comment: @Jai, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable / remove your click handlers.

The click event is triggered on mouse release.
That means, what you are doing is, when the user release the mouse, you call jQuery to further zoom the canvas.

If you remove the click handlers, the canvas should not continue to animate after mouse release.

Comment: where are click handlers? :palmface:

Comment: @AliZia Google "jquery click handler" to get some idea.

Comment: okay so I changed .click to .mousedown, and now it is quite better.

Comment: @AliZia Mousedown may have the side effect of it always zoom by at least two levels, even for a quick click.  If my quick test is right, you can simply remove that two blocks of `.click` and keep the continuous zoom.

Comment: Can I change the jerky zoom to continuous zoom until mouse is released?

Comment: If I remove single zoom, then zoom will not work on fast click. I will have to press the button to zoom. What do you say?